# Laravel: eloquent orderBy hasOne relation column using with

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a model `Orders` with a `hasOne` relation `participant`.

```php
public function participant()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\OrderParticipant', 'order_id');
}
```

I need to retrieve the `Orders` collection sorted by `participant.last_name`

My approach

```php
$orders = \App\Orders::with(['participant',])
              ->where('user_id', $user->id)  
              ->orderBy('participant.last_name')
              ->get();
```

Fails with :

> Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table \"participant\"\nLINE 1: ...1

I've tried to sort it after collected

```
return $orders->sortBy('participant.last_name');
```

But this doesn't sort at all

BTW I'm using **postgres**

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't order by hasOne directly, you have to use join

```
$orders = \App\Orders::with([
                'participant',                    
                ])
            ->where('orders.user_id', $user->id)  
            ->join('participants', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'participants.id')
            ->orderBy('participants.last_name')
            ->select('orders.*','participants.id','participants.last_name')
            ->get();
```

Comment: oh I figured this all out. I had to use select('orders.*') in order to use join

Comment: Yes now it seems to be correct, we made it! Thanks mate

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just one question: what's the point of using with here ? Ins't it redundant since we are already using a join?

Comment: You're welcome, because we are only selecting the id and name, not all of the participant data, plus its better to keep using a single standard way of accessing data which is Eloquent Relationships to maintain clean and predictable code but you can do whatever you think is better depending on your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by:

```
  // eager loading
  $orders = \App\Orders::with( [ 'participant'=> function( $q ) {
             $q->orderBy( 'last_name', 'asc/desc' );
   } ] )->get();
```

Comment: Does this sort only child "hasMany" relation?  but this will not sort the parent collection. And `participant` is "hasOne" relation, which does not need to be sorted, since its only one or null

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit redundant, but I've sorted it out by using `join`. A quite ugly though. Note the `select` part. Without it all gets messed up

```
          $orders = \App\Orders::select('orders.*')
                ->with([
                    '....',
                    'participant',
                    'participant.documents',
                    'participant.participantParent',
                    'participant.country',
                    '...'
                    ])
                ->join('order_participants', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('order_participants.order_id', '=', 'orders.id');
                })
                ->where('orders.user_id', $user->id)  
                ->where(function($q) {
                    $q->where('orders.status', '!=', 'completed')
                    ->orWhereNull('orders.status');
                })   
                ->orderBy('order_participants.last_name')
                ->orderBy('order_participants.first_name')
                ->get();
```

Since my query is a bit more complicated than in the question above, i'm posting entire code as an example. As I understand, `join` has to come before `where` statements